# How can i call function from .m file to .mm file in ios

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I have function in .mm file.

I want to call that function from my Viewcontroller file .m. But it always gives me compiler error when i am try to import .h file of c function.

I have  class file like.

```
OpenCV.h
OpenCV.mm
```

ViewController Class

```
ViewController.h
ViewController.m
```

Now when i am import `OpenCV.h` it gives me error. not able to compile

```
#import "OpenCV.h"  //Error Line
@implementation ViewController
@end
```

So how can i use .mm method in .m class

Error comes in `OpenCV.h` file

[image]

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? You mention both. Also what is the exact message the compiler gives you? Might want to edit your question to include that information.

Comment: its an error.. not a running

Comment: Maybe the space between " and OpenCV.h is a problem?

Comment: No its not a problem let me show you the error screenshoe

Comment: see screenshot when i import this error comes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that - you're trying to compile an Objective-C++ header in an Objective-C context.  You should just be able to change the name of `ViewController.m` to `ViewController.mm` to compiler it as Objective-C++ instead.

Comment: thanks for ur reply if i change ViewController.m to ViewController.mm then it may be any problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: see my error when i have done this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191860/assigning-to-enum-value-to-incompaitable-type-int