# Assigning to enum value to incompaitable type int

Tags: objective-c, enums, variable-assignment

I am using the c++ library. so **i converted my .m file to .mm file**.

Now what happens i am not able to set the enum value.

See  Enum

```
 typedef enum{
    ImageSourceTypeCamera,
    ImageSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
    ImageSourceTypeNone
  }
ImageSourceType;
```

// Property

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) ImageSourceType ImageSourceType;
```

Now when i am using this line its give me error

```
    self.ImageSourceType=2;  / / assigning to 'ImageProcessType' from incompaitable with 'int'
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your enum is named ImageProcessType, or is it ImageSourceType? Also why don't you use the name instead of a number?

Comment: sorry about that i have two enum that mixed i have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
self.ImageSourceType = ImageSourceTypePhotoLibrary
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. But  i want to set like 0 1 or 2 beacause in my delegete method i am passing the tag value. so i have to make condition if i  use the above code. if it is not possible to directly use this

Comment: Why not pass the `enum` value in your delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

To use numbers instead of names for enums, format the definition like so:

```
typedef enum{
    ImageSourceTypeCamera = 0,
    ImageSourceTypePhotoLibrary = 1,
    ImageSourceTypeNone = 2
  }
ImageSourceType;

self.ImageSourceType = 0; //ImageSourceTypeCamera
self.ImageSourceType = 1; //ImageSourceTypePhotoLibrary 
//etc...

if (self.ImageSourceType == 0) {
    //this is the same as (self.ImageSourceType == ImageSourceTypeCamera)
```

Comment: self.ImageSourceType = 0;  when i write this its give me error. i have convert my .m file to .mm thats why

Comment: I see, I don't use C++ but that must be a convention used by C++ explicitly. I always use the names of the enum.